# Display field based on http method SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, jackson, annotations, jackson-databind

I have a POJO with following fields

```
@Getter @Setter
class Dates {
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
}
```

My requirement is to display `endDate` field only in case of `GET` method response and not `POST` method. I know I can create 2 POJO to achieve this one for `GET` response and one for `POST` response. But is it possible to do this in single POJO ?? considering there are many fields in POJO and I don't want to create new POJO just for one field. Can i invoke an Annotation based on Condition, Meaning if method is `POST` hide field. Or any way that can help me get the job done in one POJO.

Comment: Can you share the controller code that you create so far?

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use separate objects for GET and POST because too much code re-use can cause components to be too heavily tied to one another and it all becomes harder to maintain. Something to keep in mind... not all duplication is bad

Answer (score 0):

There may be many ways, but here is one using `@ControllerAdvice`. Create a `ControllerAdvice` akin to what's shown below and write your logic to control the visibility of the values **just before SpringMVC serializes** the response for the caller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GCA implements ResponseBodyAdvice<CxResponse>{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public CxResponse beforeBodyWrite( Data data, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class aClass, 
            ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        if( serverHttpRequest.getMethodValue().equalsIgnoreCase( "POST" ) ) {
            data.setEndDate( null );
        }
    
        return data;
    }
}
```

Hope you realize that this `ControllerAdvice` will be called for all requests; so you may want to customize the scope of it a bit, or control it with code.